# how do I fix (key error) when registration?

Tags: python, django

I try to create a user registration when a user is signing up he has to moves to the last section which called "complete register".
I thought that mission is done by session I need to know if using a session is true in this case or not. if using a session is good how can I save the data from the first form because I get every time the key error?
I'm sure the save method in complete_register function is wrong but I have no any idea how can I continue to complete this mission.

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .forms import RegistrationForm, CompleteRegisterForm
from importlib import import_module
from django.conf import settings


def register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        user_form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if user_form.is_valid():
            user_form.save(commit=False)
            SessionStore = import_module(settings.SESSION_ENGINE).SessionStore
            user_session = SessionStore()
            user_session['continue_form'] = user_form.clean()
            # user_session.create()
            return redirect("account:complete-register")
        else:
            error_msg = "something went wrong"
        return render(request, "account/registration.html", {"user_form": user_form, "error_msg": error_msg})
    else:
        user_form = RegistrationForm()
        return render(request, "account/registration.html", {"user_form": user_form})


def complete_register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        # get the rest of data by session
        user_session = request.session
        complete_form = CompleteRegisterForm(request.POST)
        if complete_form.is_valid():
            form = user_session['continue_form'].save()
            complete_form.save()
            return redirect("music:albums")
        else:
            error_msg = "something went wrong"
        context = {"complete": complete_form, "error_msg": error_msg}
        return render(request, "account/complete_register.html", context)
    else:
        complete_form = CompleteRegisterForm()
        return render(request, "account/complete_register.html", {"complete": complete_form})
```

Comment: In `register()`, why are you creating a new `SessionStore` object instead of just using `request.session`?

Comment: Ok, I create SessionStore because I'm using SESSION_ENGINE variable into the settings file.